# Function gets called multiple times in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I would like to know why the function gets called multiple times wheh dispatch.
Also, is there any better way to do,

```
getData = (value) =>{
  const body = {
    value: value,
    cn: "TH"
  }
return body;
}

renderData(){
  console.log("starts");
  this.props.dispatch(queryData(this.getData(10)));// called repeatedly 
}

render(){
  return(
   <div>{this.renderData()}</div>
  ) 
}
```

I have updated the different scenario by same type, I need to know is there any other better way to.

scenario 2

```
getData = () =>{
  const body = {
    value: value,
    cn: "TH"
  }
return body;
}
componentDidMount=()=>{
  this.props.dispatch(queryData(this.getData()))
}
componentDidUpdate = () => {
const {allstate} = this.props.querydata 
  if(this.props.querydata){
    this.renderState(allstate);
  }
}
renderState = (data) => {
  const getId = data.map(e=>e.id); //will get array of values [2, 3, 4]
  getid.map(e=>
    this.props.dispatch(queryState(e))); //for every id dispatch props, 
  )
}
render(){
  // will gets this by componentDidMount call
  return (
    <div>

   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify state within a render method, because precisely this reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When there is render in view ,`renderData` function gets called which dispatch some action, and again this  make your component re-render.
One solution can be move your `this.renderData()` function outside the render , may be in `constructor` or `componentDidMount`

Comment: @kias thanks for reply, if i do in `componentDidMount`, and can access that props immediately by passing as arg to function before render.

Comment: main thing you should remember is that dispatch actions should never be called  directly from render function.

Comment: @kias yes  understand but I have updated scenario 2 , can you please help if any idea,

Comment: @miyavv don't make any call inside render if that call have  dispatch action  or state updates. Instead you can use `componentDidUpdate` method , check if  `this.props.querydata` is available and make `renderState` function call.

Comment: @kias thanks , I did using `componentDidUpdate` as you mentioned, but dispatch props method is not working , is it due to map, if i pass directly single `id` able to receive  , updated the scenario as mentioned,

Comment: @miyavv which dispatch is not working?  Is it inside `componentDidMount ` or `renderState`

Comment: @miyavv It is  not good practise to dispatch action inside loop as it will create multiple re-render in each loop. Try to dispatch all updates at once in one dispatch action.

Comment: @kias thanks for reply, can you proivde some sample please

Comment: @miyavv I have create a small sample  similar to your problem. Have a look https://codesandbox.io/s/reactreduxupdated-y9c4g

Answer (score 1):

`render` function will be called **every time** React class get updated.

If your action `queryData` is for fetching data to display in component, put it inside `componentDidMount`. It will only be called once when React component first mounted.